# Raspbian // ImportError: No module named PIL

Tags: pip, python-imaging-library

I am getting crazy with this error. My script used to work but I did something wrong trying to install a domoticz plugin and now i have this message

ImportError: No module named PIL

I tried almost everything I found here to solve it but no luck so far.

Comment: What are the things you have tried? Do they include `pip install Pillow`?

Answer (score 0):

It says

```
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (5.4.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) :

1. I have upgraded Python 3.5 to Python 3.6 by typing this line in a terminal :

   ```
   wget https://github.com/jjhelmus/berryconda/releases/download/v2.0.0/Berryconda3-2.0.0-Linux-armv7l.sh
   ```

   then :

   ```
   chmod +x Berryconda3-2.0.0-Linux-armv7l.sh
   ```

   then :

   ```
   ./Berryconda3-2.0.0-Linux-armv7l.sh
   ```

   then reboot the Raspberry Pi.
2. I have installed libjpeg-dev by typing this line in a terminal :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
   ```
3. At last, I have installed the pillow library by typing this line in a terminal :

   ```
   python -m pip install pillow
   ```

Finally, the "no module named 'pil'" message has disappeared.